# Replacing text in label expression of ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, python-parser, labeling

I'm trying to replace the text in a field to build a label expression. The field I'm using is called [Organizatio] and it holds the school's name. What I want is to tell ArcMap that when that name includes 'Central School District' - change it to "CSD."

This is what I have. ArcMap says it's valid but it does not make any changes.

[image]

Comment: You need to define the function without the field name in code block, in the bottom block you can use the function as `FindLabel(!Organizati!)`. Check [documentation for more information](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're telling me. I'm doing this in the label expression window. Parameters have to be passed as shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in commentaries:

Use in pre-logic script code block:

```
def FindLabel(field):
  string = field
  newstring = string.replace('Central School District ', 'CSD ')
  return newstring
```

In field definition (`test2` is the object field):

```
FindLabel( !test2! )
```

[image]

Result:

[image]

`test1` and `test2` had the same values initially